# "date" type value returned from AJAX request is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

After a GET request to a RESTful web service I am trying to print the data from the DB

```
function print(jsondata) {
    var text = "";
    $.each(jsondata, function(key, value){
        text += "Name:" + value.name + "date:" + value.date;
    });
    $("#out").append(text);
}
```

but the value of value.date is undefined. It should print the date-type value taken from the JavaDB

Comment: What is the value of the `jsondata`?

Comment: we can't guess at what is returned from server or where you are using this function. Please show usage and sample data

Comment: In other words, the value of `value.date` entirely depends on the value of `value`, which clearly depends on the value of `jsondata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is undefined, the structure of "jsondata" is not as you are expecting.

Use console.log() to kick it out to the Javascript console for inspection, or look at the raw response from the AJAX request in the network pane. If you can, post the result here.

Alternatively, open the REST URL in a new tab and use a plugin such as JSONView (on [Firefox](http://jsonview.com/), with an unofficial port to [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)) to inspect the data as well.